MutableStateFlow emission criteria explanation
I'm writing a simple todo app using compose and stateflow.
data class Task(
    val name: String,
    val isCompleted: Boolean,
    val date: Long
)
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _tasks = MutableStateFlow<List<Task>>(listOf())
    val tasks = _tasks.asStateFlow()
    val todo = mutableListOf<Task>(
        Task("Mop floor", false, System.currentTimeMillis()),
        Task("Buy soap", true, System.currentTimeMillis()+1),
        Task("Oranize toolbox", false, System.currentTimeMillis()+2)
    )

    init {
        initialize(todo)
    }

    fun initialize(todo: List<Task>) {
        _tasks.value = todo
    }

    fun toggleState(task: Task) {
        val updatedList = todo.map {
            if (it.name == task.name) task.copy(isCompleted = !it.isCompleted)
            else it
        }
        todo.clear()
        todo.addAll(updatedList)
        _tasks.value = todo
    }

My composable was not able to receive an update
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) = content {
        MaterialTheme {
            MainContent()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MainContent() {
    val viewModel: SomeViewModel = viewModel()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val tasks = viewModel.tasks.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
        ToDoList(tasks, viewModel)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ToDoList(todoList: List<Task>, vm: SomeViewModel) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(todoList) { task ->
            ToDoRow(task, vm)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ToDoRow(task: Task, vm: SomeViewModel) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable { vm.toggleState(task) }) {
        Text(text = task.name, color = if (!task.isCompleted) Color.Red else Color.Green)
        Text(text = task.date.toString(), color = if (!task.isCompleted) Color.Red else Color.Green)
    }
}

I thought it was because MutableStateFlow only emits state changes, in this case my todo list.  Even though toggleState changes an item in todo, my todo reference itself is unchanged.
So I rewrote toggleState
    fun toggleState(task: Task) {
        val updatedTask = task.copy(isCompleted = !task.isCompleted)
        val indexOf = todo.indexOfFirst { it.name == task.name }
        todo[indexOf] = updatedTask
        val list = mutableListOf<Task>()
        list.addAll(todo)
        _tasks.value = list
    }    

Now _tasks is updated with a new reference, and I expect this to be observed by my MainContent composable.  But it was not, as tasks again did not propagate a state change. I want to understand the mechanism StateFlow uses to determine a change in state.  I don't understand why it is so complicated to updatte state using StateFlow.

Your second toggleState doesn't work because structural equality between lists checks equality and order of all the elements, like in Java. So when you update the existing MutableList and then copy all the elements to a new MutableList, MutableStateFlow doesn't actually update.
To avoid this you shouldn't use MutableList for State at all, see warning about using mutable lists in docs:

Caution: Using mutable objects such as ArrayList or mutableListOf() as state in Compose causes your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app. Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, are not observable by Compose and don't trigger a recomposition when they change. Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, the recommendation is to use an observable data holder such as State<List> and the immutable listOf().

To create a new list in the toggleState you can use List.map or available in Compose function List.fastMap the way @Meet suggested:
_tasks.update { list ->
    list.fastMap { task ->
        if (task.name == taskName) task.copy(isCompleted = !task.isCompleted) else task
    }
}


Unrelated: you shouldn't pass ViewModel down to your composables, pass only event lambdas:
//...
        ToDoList(tasks, viewModel::toggleState)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ToDoList(todoList: List<Task>, toggleTask: (Task) -> Unit) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(todoList) { task ->
            ToDoRow(task) { toggleTask(task) }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ToDoRow(task: Task, toggleTask: () -> Unit) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable(onClick = toggleTask)) {
//....


"Your second toggleState doesn't work because structural equality between lists checks equality and order of all the elements"
Yes, so before the call to toggleState todo is:
reference abc pointing to Task 1, Task 2, Task 3.  In toggleState it gets changed to
Task 1, Task 2a, Task 3.  Then I create a new mutable list called list with reference xyz.  It is filled with Task 1, Task 2a, Task 3.  I assign list to _tasks.  I expect tasks to compare reference abc to xyz, and Task 2 to Task 2a.  As there is a difference based on referential and class equality, I expect stateflow to emit.

Equals returns true if references are equal. If they are not, it compares contents ( example ). _tasks contains todo instance because of _tasks.value = todo. So when you todo[indexOf] = updatedTask, you modify the same MutableList your _tasks contains. At this point _tasks.value has the updated Task 2a, same as your new list. You shouldn't have that mutable todo list at all, just init _tasks where it is declared instead of empty listOf @HukeLau_DABA

OK, so it sees the references arent equals and proceeds to check the elements, but as the todo list was updated it is comparing equal lists.  Is _tasks.update or _tasks.value preferrable?

value is thread-safe and is enough for simple cases where you just assign a new value. update executes its block atomically so it is better when you need to create the new value based on the old one, like update a list. @HukeLau_DABA

fun toggleState(task: Task) {
    val updatedTask = task.copy(isCompleted = !task.isCompleted)
    val indexOf = todo.indexOfFirst { it.name === task.name }
    todo[indexOf] = updatedTask
    val list = mutableListOf<Task>()
    list.addAll(todo)
    println("Old list reference hash code: ${System.identityHashCode(todo)}")
    println("New list reference hash code: ${System.identityHashCode(list)}")
    _tasks.value = list
    println("New _tasks list reference hash code: ${System.identityHashCode(_tasks.value)}")
}



StateFlow checks for equality using == (reference equality for lists) before emitting a new value. When you update elements within the same list reference, the list’s reference itself does not change, and StateFlow does not emit any new value to observers.
try this both work it my case
fun toggleState(task: Task) {
    // Map over the list to create a new list with the updated task
    val updatedList = _tasks.value.map {
        if (it.name == task.name) it.copy(isCompleted = !it.isCompleted) else it
    }
    // Set the new list to `_tasks`, which will trigger StateFlow to emit the new value
    _tasks.value = updatedList
}

or
fun toggleState(task: Task) {
    _tasks.update {taskList ->
        taskList.map {
            if (it.name == task.name) it.copy(isCompleted = !it.isCompleted) else it
        }
    }
}



so it looks like you create the new state from _tasks instead of the todo list.  It works, but why didn't creating new state from todo list function similarly to properly update _tasks flow?  Plus back to my original question, what causes MutableStateFlow to propagate a change, it doesnt appear to do so simply by comparing previous and current values of what it stores via equals(), in this case for kotlin's List class.

in few month ago i have same question. after i searching video and article see it new reference need it. i prefer second option directly you can update child.

But my 2nd version of toggleState uses a new list.  list.addAll(todo) copies all the elements from todo, and then I update _tasks with this new list, so why didn't the flow emit if it is a new reference, it should be different per ===, no?

if use === and == both case not work because same reference use it so can not emit or update

i not much detail but i use update function

and i not prefer indexOfFirst because if name not exist so index also -1 and after update list so throw exception. you need check if (index != -1) after update

https://youtu.be/JfCivo5qJkI?si=WL_3A5Ovy1HWvWyH

again check  answer it we use hashcode
